# How to get FPS in JOGL?

Tags: java, frame-rate, jogl

I currently trying to output my FPS using JOGL, to no avail. I have tried many things such as
`glAutoDrawable.getAnimator().getLastFPS()` but it returns 0.0. I have also tried using `glAutoDrawable.getAnimator().setUpdateFPSFrames(3, System.out);` but it never logs the FPS. I am trying to get the FPS of the ENTIRE application, not a animation.

I have checked [Jogl animator always says FPS is 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382454/jogl-animator-always-says-fps-is-0) but this requires a `Animator` object which I am not using. When using a `new Animator` (`glAutoDrawable.setAnimator(new Animator());`) the FPS still returns 0.0.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
package ***.core.graphics;

import com.jogamp.opengl.*;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.Animator;
import ***.log.Log;
import ***.tests.utils.GameTestMethods;

public class GameCanvas implements GLEventListener{
...
    @Override
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable glAutoDrawable) {
        GL2 glDraw = glAutoDrawable.getGL().getGL2();

        gameTestMethods.onRender(glDraw); // Draws a rectangle, not the issue.
        Log.log(Log.LogLevel.DEBUG, "FPS: "+glAutoDrawable.getAnimator().getLastFPS());//Trying to log FPS, returns 0.0 every time.
    }

    @Override
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable glAutoDrawable) {
        glAutoDrawable.setAnimator(new Animator()); // No clue what i'm doing here...
        glAutoDrawable.getAnimator().setUpdateFPSFrames(3, System.out); // NEVER logs FPS...
    }
...

}
```

Would this be possible, or would I need my own FPS counter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jogl animator always says FPS is 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382454/jogl-animator-always-says-fps-is-0)

Comment: @MattU I have already checked that link, it requires an `Animator` which I am not using. When using a `new Animator()`, the FPS is still 0.0.

Comment: It's not magic, you'll have to count the frame rate by yourself as you don't use an animator, which isn't a big deal as you use a GLEventListener.